# why threading.Timer function not called with Gtk.main in python

Tags: python, gtk, python-multithreading

I am trying to poll a function in a Gtk application . The code is ...

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
import sys,threading

def destroy(k):
print "destroyed"
sys.exit()

def poll():
print "called it "
t=threading.Timer(1,poll)
t.start()

build=Gtk.Builder()
build.add_from_file('test.glade')    # it just creates a top level window
window=build.get_object("boxy")
build.connect_signals({"destroyit":destroy})
window.show_all()
t=threading.Timer(1,poll)
t.start()
Gtk.main()
```

The poll function is not executed .. But if I remove Gtk.main() , it works fine ... So what is going on .. Why does it work without main and not with main ...and how do I execute a polling function in this ..any other alternatives than threading.timer ?

EDIT: I found the way around by using GObject.timeout_add(5000,poll) but still I want to know , why does the threading.Timer function doesnt execute ...

Answer (score 0):

well I found the answer to my question...

```
GObject.timeout_add(5000,poll)
```